# how can make drawable background to highlight tab like image below

Tags: android, image

How can I make tab like this, with icon and highlight:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to used images with transparent area around corn, tomato and papaya and set background color as while if it is not selected tab.

And when user selects one tab then change its background color same as bottom layout and background color of other tab will remain white.

And when click on another tab change background color of previously selected Tab.

you can use `drawable` `xml` files to make round shape for both one side bottom right and second for both top right and left round shape image.

Comment: the problem occur is that am not be able to get a round corner

Comment: You need to make two set of corn image one with circle and one with round shape with transparent area.

Comment: still i do not get edge shape